# Controlar una excepción con JUnit

Tags: java, junit

Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios con JUnit y en concreto estoy evaluando un método que sirve para ingresar dinero, este método cuando detecta una cantidad negativa, me devuelve una excepción diciendome que no puede ingresar esa cantidad.

Cuando llego a JUnit tengo un problema, si pongo el saldo de la cuenta a 0, debo esperar cero, pero la prueba unitaria me devuelve como fallo y la excepción, ¿alguna forma de hacer una prueba que precisamente espere ese resultado y me lo de como valido?

```
/**
 * Test Dos para el metodo ingresas con una cantidad negativa, este testdebe
 * fallar y decinos que no se puede sacar una cantidad negativa
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@Test
public void testIngresarTres() throws Exception {
    double cantidad = -250.0;
    double esperado = 0.0;
    CCuenta instance = new CCuenta();

    System.out.println("Test ingresar 3");
    instance.ingresar(cantidad);

    assertEquals(esperado, instance.estado());

}
```

He estado revisando la documentación y he visto assertEqualsSame pero no se como podria usarlo, gracias

Comment: que versión de junit usas, 3, 4 o 5?

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución la comparto por si es de ayuda, simplemente he incluido en un try catch el método al que llamo, y en el mismo try llamo al fail "No ha saltado la excepción" para que me salte un fail, ya  que se que tiene que saltar la excepción si o si, por lo tanto si me salta la captura y al método assertEquals le paso el parametro esperado y resultado como 0, que es como esta.

```
 /**
 * Test Tres para el metodo ingresas con una cantidad negativa, este test debe
 * fallar y decinos que no se puede sacar una cantidad negativa
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@Test
public void testIngresarTres() throws Exception {
    double cantidad = -250.0;
    double esperado = 0.0;
    CCuenta instance = new CCuenta();

    System.out.println("Test ingresar 3");

    try {
        instance.ingresar(cantidad);
        fail("No ha saltado la excepción");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertEquals(0.0, 0.0);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como solucion alternativa a lo que propones con `try`-`catch`, si no te interesa validar el contenido de la excepcion, puedes hacer el test de la siguiente manera:

```
@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void testIngresarTres() {
    double cantidad = -250.0;
    double esperado = 0.0;
    CCuenta instance = new CCuenta();

    System.out.println("Test ingresar 3");

    instance.ingresar(cantidad);

    /* codigo no ejecutado */
    assertEquals(0.0, 0.0);
}
```

El unico inconveniente es que una vez es lanzada la excepcion en tu metodo `.ingresar` el codigo que venga despues no sera ejecutado, como por ejemplo el `assertEquals(...)`.